# Laravel named route not defined when it is

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm doing a form where a user may whether authorize or refuse an `askedRapport`.
Here it is:

`askRapportShow.blade.php` blade view :

```
<form action="{{route('authorize', $askedRapport->id)}}" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea> <br>
      <button type="submit" formaction="{{route('authorize', $askedRapport->id)}}" class="btn btn-success">Autoriser</button>
      <button type="submit" formaction="{{route('refuse', $askedRapport->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger">Refuser</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In `web.php` file for the routes definition:

```
// RAPPORT ASKING MANAGEMENT
Route::post('askedRapport/{id}', 'manageAskedRapportController@authorize')->name('authorize');
Route::post('askedRapport/{id}', 'manageAskedRapportController@refuse')->name('refuse');
// RAPPORT ASKING MANAGEMENT--END
```

and the controller `manageAskedRapportController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class manageAskedRapportController extends Controller
{

    public function authorize($id){
        return view('welcome');
    }

    public function refuse($id){
        return view('unauthorized');
    }
}
```

While the route is well defined I think, I still get this error :
[image]

Does someone get why I'm having this issue? Any help is very welcome

**Edit**

If this can help, when I type the `php artisan route:list` command, this is what I get :

```
   ErrorException  : Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\manageAskedRapportController::authorize($id) should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::authorize($ability, $arguments = Array)

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\monapp\app\Http\Controllers\manageAskedRapportController.php:17
    13|
    14|     public function refuse($id){
    15|         return view('unauthorized');
    16|     }
  > 17| }
    18|

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError("Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\manageAskedRapportController::authorize($id) should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::authorize($ability, $arguments = Array)", "C:\xampp\htdocs\monapp\app\Http\Controllers\manageAskedRapportController.php", ["C:\xampp\htdocs\monapp\vendor\composer/../../app\Http\Controllers\manageAskedRapportController.php"])
      C:\xampp\htdocs\monapp\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:444

  2   include()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\monapp\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:444

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: could you post result of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Why you use same route twice ?

Comment: `refuse` always override the `authorize` route because the url is identical.

Comment: @JitheshJose, um, is that a problem? As long as it is different actions, won't it just go to the mentioned function in the controller when the corresponding button is clicked? I may be wrong

Comment: No you can't use the same url in different routes.

Comment: Refer this link.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104104/how-to-make-a-route-with-different-controllers-and-the-same-urls-with-laravel-4

Comment: I used to use the same route but indeed it was with different verbs (get then post). I get it twisted this time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the route and try.I think the second route will override the first one.So whenevr you try to use the first route,laravel may show `route not found exception`.

```
Route::post('askedRapport/{id}/authorize', 'manageAskedRapportController@authorize')->name('authorize');
Route::post('askedRapport/{id}/refuse', 'manageAskedRapportController@refuse')->name('refuse');
```

Answer (score 0):

Form action route are defined as

```
<form action="{{route('authorize'), [$askedRapport->id] }}" method="POST">
```

Comment: `{{route('authorize'), [$askedRapport->id] }}` and `{{route('authorize'), $askedRapport->id }}` are same.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the slash `/`.

Try defining route like this:

```
Route::post('/askedRapport/{id}', 'manageAskedRapportController@authorize')->name('authorize');
Route::post('/askedRapport/{id}', 'manageAskedRapportController@refuse')->name('refuse');
```